# Include pattern in list.dirs

Tags: r, loops, directory

surely a very newbish question, but how do I include a pattern inside a list.dirs function?

For example, list.files function

```
Imagery=list.files(full.names=TRUE, recursive=TRUE, pattern= "*20m*.tif$")
```

returns all the files that have 20m in their name and have .tif as extension.

But when i try to apply this logic to list.dirs

```
directories=list.dirs(full.names = TRUE, recursive=TRUE, pattern="R10m" )
```

i get this error:

```
Error in list.dirs(full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE, pattern = "R10m") : 
unused argument (pattern = "R10m")
```

Hope I am not missing something obvious here.
My goal is to get the full path of all directories that have a folder named "R10m". I have a lot of folder that have many subdirectories, and most of them have similar structure. I would like to list only those that have this folder, and within them list all files that are tifs. I know I can get the files I need with only list.files options, but I need the directory path and file names later as variables.

Thank you beforehand for your time,

Best regards,
Davor

Comment: See `?list.dirs`. There is no pattern argument for this function. Probably wrap the function in `grep` with value=TRUE and maybe fixed=TRUE.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Three alternatives:

```
dirs <- list.dirs()
dirs <- dirs[ grepl(your_pattern, dirs) ]
```

or

```
dirs <- list.dirs()
dirs <- grep(your_pattern, dirs, value = TRUE)
```

or

```
files <- list.files(pattern = your_pattern, recursive = TRUE, include.dirs = TRUE)
dirs <- files[ file.info(files)$isdir ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, this is the solution that worked for me.

Comment: Would be possible to search all dir with a specific name recursively with that approach? Ex. I want the path of all dir exactly named 'foo'.

Comment: @fmassica, with the use of `recursive=`, `pattern=`, and `path=` it should be rather direct. If it isn't that clear, I suggest you open a new question.

Answer (score 5):

`dir`, unlike `list.dirs` provides that functionality:

```
dir(path = ".", pattern = NULL, all.files = FALSE,
                full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE,
                ignore.case = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE, no.. = FALSE)
```

In your example:

```
directories <- dirs(full.names = TRUE, recursive=TRUE, pattern="R10m")
```

Yes, I also find it strange that there are 2 base functions to list directories, one of which, despite the name similarity with `list.files` doesn't provide the same like for like functionality. If someone knows the reason for this I would be very interested in knowing.

**Update**

After Gregor's comment, I decided to create a reproducible example to test my solution:

```
test_dirs <- c(
   paste0(c(1:3), "R10m", rep("a", 3)),
   paste0(c(1:3), "R200m", rep("a", 3))
)

for (test_dir in test_dirs){
   dir.create(test_dir)
}

list.dirs()
```

> [1] "."                 "./1R10ma"          "./1R200ma"         [4]
>   "./2R10ma"          "./2R200ma"         "./3R10ma"          [7]
>   "./3R200ma"         "./solo_kit-figure"

```
dir()
```

> [1] "1R10ma"          "1R200ma"         "2R10ma"          "2R200ma"
>   [5] "3R10ma"          "3R200ma"         "a1.bed"          "a2.bed"
>   [9] "a.bed"           "solo_kit-figure" "solo_kit.md"

```
dir(pattern = "R10m")
# dir(pattern = "*R10m")
# also works
```

> "1R10ma" "2R10ma" "3R10ma"

`dir` also lists files, so if the pattern fits both files and directories it might be a problem, but I guess that for most application it will work fine.

Comment: I'm not sure that this works... isn't `dir` just an alias for `list.files`? (Which I too find confusing). If you look at the code for `dir` it just calls `list.files` without even modifying any arguments, and the results don't distinguish between files and folders.

Comment: I'd be willing to bet it was included for backwards compatibility with S or something like that.

Comment: @Gregor, updated with a test. It also list files if they match the pattern. And no, it is not, surprisingly, an alias for `list.files`.

Comment: @Gregor, could be backwards compatibility with S - as is all of R - but it is a strange one.

Comment: But if you run `list.files(pattern = "R10m")`, you get the exact same output as you do from `dir(pattern = "R10m")`, right?  And type `dir` in your console to view the function code, and see that the entire function is one line, a call to `list.files`. And then run `identical(dir, list.files)` and the `TRUE` result confirms that the function bodies are identical?

Comment: You are right! Sorry, I misread and thought you said dir = list.dirs. My bad.

Comment: Thank you both for your responses. Unfortunately, pattern fits both files and directories so that is a problem. But luckily, the solution is what r2evans wrote above. Best regards, Davor.